# Delete a repeated part of post title in WordPress

Tags: title

All of my posts have the words
(With Table)
at the end of post title.

I want to delete this part in every post title but can't do it manually because there are 10,000+ posts

I tried Better Search Replace plugin but it tells me I have 21,000 matches whereas I only have 12275 posts in my WordPress (there are no draft, pending or trash posts)

Is there any easy way to do this bulk change by using some code or plugin? I will take backup before trying a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have access to your database, as every posts are registered in the (wp_/ or whatever is your prefix )posts , you can probably do it via sql
something like

```
update wp_posts
SET post_title = substring(post_title,1, CHAR_LENGTH(post_title) - 10))
WHERE post_title like '%With Table'
```